# Radio buttons displayed in different sizes in iPad

Tags: html, css, ipad

[image]

Guys before i begin, i would request you to take a look at the image. The issue is in iPad with radio buttons. Both radio buttons are displayed in different sizes in iPad. In chrome emulator, it displays correctly and i'm not able to figure out what is the problem. There's no difference in marking up these two radio buttons. They're the same.

```
<div class="newbjradio" data-bind="visible:PaymentViewModel.PaymentCOD() == true">
    <input type="radio" name="rdoPayment" value="COD"> <span>Cash on delivery</span>
</div>

<div class="newbjradio" data-bind="visible:PaymentViewModel.PaymentOfflineBT() == true">
    <input type="radio" name="rdoPayment" value="BT"> <span>Bank transfer</span>
</div>

.newbjradio input[type=radio] {
    width: 20px !important;
    height: 20px !important;
    background: #fff;
}
```

Any idea what could be the cause?

Comment: you can look if there's a css `input[type="radio"]:checked {...` that makes the selected choice have a different size.

Comment: @freestock.tk - you're right. For some reason, one radio button is in checked state. Need to check with back end developers.

Answer (score 0):

Used this css:
these are in checked state ,so to back it with this code

```
input:checked + span {
 display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is hiding the `background` of the `button`, try changing the `background`!

```
input:checked { background: #333333 !important; }
```